# React Native: Screen only rendering when safing file? flatlist not showing items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to fetch data before screen is rendered so i can show the fetched data in a flatlist. but its not working. how can i fix that problem ?

```html
export default function NewRecipe() {

  const user = useContext(AuthContext);


  const [userIngredients, setUserIngredients] = useState([]);
  const [userRecipes, setUserRecipes] = useState([]);


  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
      var ingredients = await firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).get();
      var labels = []
      ingredients.data().ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
        labels.push(ingredient.label)
      })
      setUserIngredients(labels)
      console.log(userIngredients)
      setUserRecipes([])
    }
    getUserData()
  }, [])

  var apiKey = "ab9b5a9a88c445a8a41206991fd88f42"

  function fetchRecipes(userIngredients) {
    var number = 5
    var url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=" + userIngredients.join(",") + "&number=" + String(number) + "&apiKey=" + apiKey
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if (responseJson && responseJson.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            var newRecipe = {
              id: responseJson[i].id,
              title: responseJson[i].title,
              image: responseJson[i].image,
              ingredients: userIngredients
            }
            userRecipes.unshift(newRecipe)
          }
          firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).update({
            recipes: userRecipes
          })
          console.log("Rezepte", userRecipes)
        }
        else {
          console.log("hdf")
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }

  const renderRecipe = ({ item }) => {
    console.log(item)
    return (
      <View style={styles.item} >
        <View >
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </View >
    )
  }

  console.log(1)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => fetchRecipes(userIngredients)}><Text>Press</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      <FlatList
        data={userRecipes}
        renderItem={renderRecipe}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}>
      </FlatList>
    </View >
  );
}
```

in the fetchIngredient function i fetch the recipes from the api and i get the data. but it only shows the items for 2secs when i save the file. i want the items to get rendered when i tab into the screen in my tabbottombar

Comment: Edit and delete your apiKey is dangerous dude

Comment: if i safe the the file it appends the recipes again into my array so i have more then 5 how can i fix this

Comment: rajesh solve your issue I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating `userRecipes` state in fetchRecipes function.

You can do something like this

```
if (responseJson && responseJson.length > 0) {
   const newRecipes = []
   for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
       const newRecipe = {
           id: responseJson[i].id,
           title: responseJson[i].title,
           image: responseJson[i].image,
           ingredients: userIngredients
       }
       newRecipes.unshift(newRecipe) // adding in a temporary array
   }
   setUserRecipes(newRecipes) // updating the state without mutating.

   firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).update({
       recipes: newRecipes
   })
}
```

Comment: i got problem with the useLayoutEffect it only works when i safe the file but i want it to get the data when it want to render the screen

Comment: now i need to safe the file and then i can use the fetch function but thats not what i want

Comment: I didn't get your requirement correctly. Can you please create a sandbox?

In general you don't really need `useLayoutEffect` where you are just showing a list, which will be fetched on page load. `useEffect` is fine for that.

You are mentioning 'on saving the file' I guess. Are you talking about hot reloading?

Comment: i fixed it with useEffect

Comment: Im using expo. And i the data from useEffect gets only fetched when i save the file on my computer